# Can my android app catch and store notifications pushed from many other apps to notification bar

Tags: android, notifications

I want my android app to read all notification messages which are being sent to notification bar by different apps. Is it possible to do so? And what would be the best way?

Comment: AFIK it is only possible if you implement a Accessibility service.

Answer (score 0):

No you can not access it. at least from what i know these notifications don't belong to your application thus it would break the privacy of the user...

Answer (score 0):

On Android 4.3 and higher, you can set up [a `NotificationListenerService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html) to be informed about `Notification`s coming and going.